# How to show $2l+1\equiv (2l+1)^{4n+1}\pmod{5}, \forall l$ in the integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How would I go about showing  $2l+1\equiv (2l+1)^{4n+1}\pmod{5}, \forall l$ in the integers?

I tried this, but got stuck.
\begin{align*}
                2l+1&\equiv x\pmod{5}\\
                (2l+1)^{4n+1}\pmod{5} &\equiv x^{4n+1}\pmod{5}
 \end{align*}

I'm not sure what to do from here.

Should I do even/odd cases for $l$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$(2l+1)^{4n+1}=[(2l+1)^{4}]^n(2l+1)$$
then refer to [**Fermat's little theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

$$a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$$

Comment: How do we show gcd$(a,p)=1$?

Comment: What about the identity if $p\mid 2l+1$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\bmod 5\!:\,\ \color{#c00}a(\color{#0a0}a^{\large\color{#0a0}4n}\!-\!1)\equiv 0\,$ if $\,\color{#c00}{a\equiv 0},\,$ and also if $\,a\not\equiv 0\,$ by $\,\color{#0a0}{a^{\large 4}\equiv 1}\,$ by Fermat

Answer (score 0):

if $2l+1=5k=>5k\equiv (5k)^{4n+1}\pmod{5}$.$$$$
if $2l+1=5k+1=>5k+1\equiv (5k+1)^{4n+1}\pmod{5}<=>1\equiv1\pmod 5$$$$$
if $2l+1=5k+3=>5k+3\equiv (5k+3)^{4n+1}\pmod{5}<=>3\equiv3^{4n+1}\equiv 3\cdot 81^n\equiv3\cdot 1^n\pmod 5$.